# In React.js how do you create a link to change the active tab using react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am using [React-bootstrap Tabs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tabs) and I want to create a link within my tab content that changes the active tab and opens the second tab.

For example:

```
<Tabs ...>
   <Tab eventKey={1} ...>
      Click this <TabLink eventKey={2} ...>link</TabLink>
   </Tab>
   <Tab eventKey={2} ...>
      <TabLink eventKey={2} ...>
         ...
      </TabLink>
   </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Obviously, TabLink does not exists as a component - and this is my question how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Tabs` component has a prop called `activeKey` - use your component's state to control that value ([as shown in this example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tabs-controlled)), and then use an `a` tag with an onClick for your link.

Here's an example, adapted from the one I linked above - I can't test it right now, but it should give you the right idea.

```
const LinkedTabs = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      key: 1
    };
  },

  goToTab(key) {
    this.setState({key});
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs activeKey={this.state.key}>
        <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">
          <span>Click this </span><a onClick={() => this.goToTab(2)}>link</a>
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">Tab 2 content</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3" disabled>Tab 3 content</Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
});
```